# Fluid properties

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I cannot understand the following sentence,

> Without flow , however, shearing stresses cannot exist, and compression stress or pressure is the only stress to be considered.

(from *A Physical Introduction to Fluid Mechanics*, by A. J. Smits, John Wiley & Sons, 2000)

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you explain what you find confusing about the sentence? Have you looked up the terms *shear stress* etc on Wikipedia to check what they mean?

Comment: when we apply a force on a solid , the shear stress will bring back the solid to it's original shape . So we can consider the fluid motion continues under the application of a shear stress , we may define the fluid as : a substance that can't sustain a shear stress when at rest , and the inability of fluids to resist shearing gives them their characteristics ability to change their shape or flow

Answer (score 3):

You can essentially *define* fluids as those that will "keep deforming" if subjected to a constant shear stress.

Intuitively, if you take a solid and apply a shear stress, it will yield a bit and then apply back enough force to come to equilibrium. For a fluid, on the other hand, consider blowing over the top of a full glass of water, which will pull the surface tangentially to itself: this will set up a circulating flow that will continue for as long as you keep blowing.

As it turns out, it's quite hard to provide a simple formal definition of what distinguishes solids and fluids, and this property is the easiest handle on what makes something fluid or solid. It works for "normal" materials, and borderline materials are decided on this basis.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking:

In solids shear stress is proportional to shear deformation.

In fluids shear stress is proportional to rate of shear deformation.

Answer (score 0):

Common sense tells me that shear stresses occur when things are moving relative to each other. Therefore, if nothing is moving (no flow), there will be no shear stresses: everything is static. However, a fluid will still exert a pressure on its surroundings.

Comment: when we apply a force on a solid , the shear stress will bring back the solid to it's original shape . So we can consider the fluid motion continues under the application of a shear stress , we may define the fluid as : a substance that can't sustain a shear stress when at rest , and the inability of fluids to resist shearing gives them their characteristics ability to change their shape or flow

Comment: @user2687618 So, what is there first? Shear stress or flow?